# How to save model into RDS file in Python?

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, deep-learning, rpy2

I used tensorflow to build a neural network model, and I need to save this model into RDS file. I tried to use `rpy2`,

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
saveRDS = robjects.r['saveRDS']
saveRDS(model, 'model.rds')
```

However the error shows that

```
NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2rpy' not defined for objects of type '<class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>'
```

I was wondering are there any ways of converting the model to RDS using python?

Comment: Not every R object can be serialised into rds format. In particular, complicated ML models from Keras/Tensorflow/etc will typically have their own serialisation procedures

Comment: Why RDS? Since this is a Python object, why not pickle? Load in R with `reticulate` counterpart of `rpy2`.

Comment: I think a better way to phrase it that _every native R object_ can be serialized, but keras or tensorflow model fits may still contain non-R data as external pointers.  These do have native serialization though.